# Extracting mail data out of MS Outlook's generic mailbox

Tags: python, email, iteration, outlook

This code extract data from generic mailbox mapped by MS Outlook
I failed at recursive iteration in subfolders, so it stays as iterative one.
Added ASCII encoding to deal with crazy national symbols in body/subjects.
My main target is to ensure scalablity and prevent it being slow (iteration over 100 generic mailboxes)

````
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pg
import time
import datetime


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

mailboxNamesList=['Generic_Mailbox']

#test input
#mailboxName = pg.prompt('please input mailbox name and press enter', 'mailbox name')
#main(mailboxName)


start = time.time()

date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

class Calc():
    def itemLoop(iterator, folderName, msg):
        arrFolder= []
        iRow = 1

        for iterator in msg:
            if iterator.Class == 43:
                mailDate=str(iterator.ReceivedTime)[0:10]
                mailDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(mailDate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                if date<mailDate:
                    line= [iRow]
                    body=str(iterator.Body)[0:100].replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', ''). replace(',', ' ')
                    body=body.encode(encoding='ascii',errors='replace')

                    line.append(folderName)
                    line.append(str(iterator.SenderEmailAddress).encode(encoding='ascii',errors='replace'))
                    line.append(str(iterator.Subject).encode(encoding='ascii',errors='replace'))
                    line.append(str(iterator.ReceivedTime))
                    line.append(Calc.action(iterator))
                    line.append(body)
                    line.append(iterator.Importance)
                    line.append(iterator.Sensitivity)
                    line.append(iterator.UnRead)
                    line.append(iterator.Categories.replace(',', ';'))
                    line.append(Calc.autoreply(iterator))
                    line.append(iterator.OutlookVersion)

                    arrFolder.append(line)
                    iRow +=1

        npFolder=np.asarray(arrFolder)
        return(npFolder)

    def action(iterator):
        actionCode=iterator.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")

        if actionCode==102:
            actionDone="replied"
        if actionCode==103:
            actionDone="replied to all"
        if actionCode==104:
            actionDone="forwarded"
        if actionCode==0:
            actionDone="no action taken"

        return(actionDone)

    def autoreply(iterator):
        subject=str(iterator.Subject).encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='replace').strip()
        ifAuto='No'
        autoList=['Auto', 'b"Auto', 'Out of Office', 'b"Out of Office']

        for phrase in autoList:
            try:
                if subject[len(phrase)]==phrase:
                    ifAuto='Yes'
                    #move!
            except:        
                pass

        return(ifAuto)


def main(mailboxName):

    folder = outlook.Folders.Item(str(mailboxName))
    inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
    msg = inbox.Items
    arrMailbox=np.array([['index','Folder','SenderEmailAddress', 'Subject', 'ReceivedTime', 'Action taken', 'Body', 'Importance', 'Sensitivity', 'Not readed', 'Categories', 'Autoreply', 'OutlookVersion']])

    for i in folder.Folders:
        if str(i)=='Inbox':
            box = folder.Folders.Item(str(i))
            msg = box.Items
            print(str(i)+": "+str(len(msg)))
            arrFolder=Calc.itemLoop(i, 'inbox', msg)
            arrMailbox = np.concatenate((arrMailbox, arrFolder))

            for j in i.Folders:
                subFolder=i.Folders
                box = subFolder.Item(str(j))
                msg = box.Items
                print(str(j)+": "+str(len(msg)))
                arrFolder=Calc.itemLoop(j, box, msg)
                if arrFolder.size!=0:
                    arrMailbox = np.concatenate((arrMailbox, arrFolder))
                try:
                    for k in j.Folders:
                        subFolder=j.Folders
                        box = subFolder.Item(str(k))
                        msg = box.Items
                        if msg != None:
                            print(str(k)+": "+str(len(msg)))
                        arrFolder=Calc.itemLoop(k, box, msg)   
                        if arrFolder.size!=0:
                            arrMailbox = np.concatenate((arrMailbox, arrFolder))
                        try:    
                            for l in k.Folders:
                                subFolder=k.Folders
                                print(str(l)+": "+str(len(msg)))
                                arrFolder=Calc.itemLoop(l, box, msg)   
                                if arrFolder.size!=0:
                                    arrMailbox = np.concatenate((arrMailbox, arrFolder))
                        except:
                            pass
                except:
                    try:    
                        for l in k.Folders:
                            subFolder=k.Folders
                            print(str(l)+": "+str(len(msg)))
                            arrFolder=Calc.itemLoop(l, box, msg)   
                            if arrFolder.size!=0:
                                arrMailbox = np.concatenate((arrMailbox, arrFolder))
                    except:
                        pass
        if str(i)=='Junk E-Mail' or str(i) == 'Deleted Items' or str(i) == 'Sent Items' :
            box = folder.Folders.Item(str(i))
            msg = box.Items
            print(str(i)+": "+str(len(msg)))
            arrFolder=Calc.itemLoop(i, str(i), msg)   
            if arrFolder.size!=0:
                arrMailbox = np.concatenate((arrMailbox, arrFolder))

    np.savetxt(str(mailboxName)+'_'+ str(datetime.date.today()) +'.csv', arrMailbox, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')

for i in mailboxNamesList:
    main(i)

end = time.time()    
pg.alert(text=(str(end - start) + ' seconds'), title='DONE', button='PERFECT')
```
````

Answer (score 1):

### Capture global variables elsewhere

These:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

mailboxNamesList=['Generic_Mailbox']

#test input
#mailboxName = pg.prompt('please input mailbox name and press enter', 'mailbox name')
#main(mailboxName)


start = time.time()

date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

either belong as members of a class, or as local variables passed through function arguments.

### lower_snake_case

`itemLoop`

should be

`item_loop`

and so on for `arrFolder`, etc.

### Naming

For this code:

```
for iterator in msg
```

Don't just call it `iterator`. Maybe call it `messages`. Name a thing based on its business purpose, not what type of Python variable it is.

### Implicit slice start

```
str(iterator.ReceivedTime)[0:10]
```

can be

```
str(iterator.ReceivedTime)[:10]
```

### Successive append

Rather than

```
                line.append(folderName)
                line.append(str(iterator.SenderEmailAddress).encode(encoding='ascii',errors='replace'))
                line.append(str(iterator.Subject).encode(encoding='ascii',errors='replace'))
                line.append(str(iterator.ReceivedTime))
                line.append(Calc.action(iterator))
                line.append(body)
                line.append(iterator.Importance)
                line.append(iterator.Sensitivity)
                line.append(iterator.UnRead)
                line.append(iterator.Categories.replace(',', ';'))
                line.append(Calc.autoreply(iterator))
                line.append(iterator.
```

consider

```
line.extend([
    folderName,
    (str(iterator.SenderEmailAddress).encode(encoding='ascii',errors='replace'),
    # ...
])
```

### Codes

For these numbers:

```
    if actionCode==102:
        actionDone="replied"
    if actionCode==103:
        actionDone="replied to all"
    if actionCode==104:
        actionDone="forwarded"
    if actionCode==0:
        actionDone="no action taken"
```

make an `enum.Enum`, perhaps

```
class ActionCode(Enum):
    REPLIED = 102
    REPLIED_ALL = 103
    ...
```

### Return is a not a function

Drop the parens here:

```
    return(actionDone)
```

### Don't swallow exceptions

This:

```
        except:        
            pass
```

needs to die. At the absolute most, catch the specific exception you need to ignore.

### Boolean

`autoreply` should not return `'Yes'` or `'No`', it should return a boolean, to optionally be stringified by other code.

### Formatting

```
str(i)+": "+str(len(msg))
```

should be

```
f'{i}: {len(msg)}'
```

### Use `is`

This

```
                    if msg != None:
```

should be

```
if msg is not None
```

### Set membership

```
if str(i)=='Junk E-Mail' or str(i) == 'Deleted Items' or str(i) == 'Sent Items' :
```

should be

```
if str(I) in {'Junk E-Mail', 'Deleted Items', 'Sent Items'}:
```